# Derivation of Boltzmann distribution using Stirling's approximation

Tags: statistical-mechanics, physical-chemistry

I'm reading Physical Chemistry by Engel Reid and I have trouble with deriving the natural log of the weight of a configuration.
$$\begin{aligned}
\ln W &=\ln N !-\ln \prod_{n} a_{n} ! \\
&=N \ln N-\sum_{n} a_{n} \ln a_{n}
\end{aligned}$$
where $a_{n}$ is the occupation number of an energy level

I do understand $N=\sum_{n} a_{n}$ and $\ln \prod_{n} a_{n} =\sum_{n}\ln a_{n}$. However, I don't know how to come to the 2nd line. A step by step derivation would absolutely be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it that you are happy with the first equation that you quoted. The second equation follows by using Stirling's formula (truncated version) for $N!$ and for the {$a_n!$}, and then tidying.

$$\ln W =N \ln N-N\ -\Sigma_n (a_n \ln a_n - a_n) $$
So
$$\ln W =N \ln N-N\ -\Sigma_n a_n \ln a_n +\Sigma_n a_n $$
So
$$\ln W =N \ln N-N\ -\Sigma_n a_n \ln a_n +N $$
So
$$\ln W =N \ln N -\Sigma_n a_n \ln a_n  $$

Comment: There is another equation in the book that i cant quite follow. Would be really grateful if you can help me out with it.

Comment: $$\frac{d \ln W}{d a_{n}}=\ln N+N\left(\frac{1}{N}\right)-\left(\ln a_{n}+1\right)=-\ln \left(\frac{a_{n}}{N}\right) \text{Eq.1}$$ $$\begin{aligned}
d \ln W &=0=\sum_{n}-\ln \left(\frac{a_{n}}{N}\right) d a_{n}+\alpha \sum_{n} d a_{n}-\beta \sum_{n} \varepsilon_{n} d a_{n} \\
&=\sum_{n}\left(-\ln \left(\frac{a_{n}}{N}\right)+\alpha-\beta \varepsilon_{n}\right) d a_{n}
\end{aligned} \text{Eq.2}$$

Comment: I dont know why the first $\sum_{n}$ in Eq.2 comes from

Comment: The writer is using this: $$df(a_1, a_2 ...) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial a_1}da_1+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial a_2}da_2...$$ in which $f(a_1, a_2 ...) = \ln W$

Comment: Ah I do understand the partial derivative -> $d \ln W = -\ln \left(\frac{a_{n}}{N}\right) \cdot d a_{n} $. The last 2 terms are associated with Lagrange's multipliers but im not sure about the $\sum_{n}$. It's a sum over $n$ but there are no arguments and how does $d \ln W$ have this term?

Comment: In my last comment I wrote the variation in ln $W$ as a sum of terms, one term in $da_1$, one in $da_2$ and so on. So I could have written $$d\ln W=\sum_i \frac {\partial (\ln W)}{\partial a_i} da_i.$$